# Does "redirected" mean that the LWA(Lost Wage Assistant) is a success to the FEMA(Federal Emergency Management Agency)?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Currently reading [**this article,**](https://www.yahoo.com/money/coronavirus-stimulus-states-are-running-out-of-unemployment-benefits-ordered-by-president-trump-161507895.html)

There is a line saying

> On August 8, Trump signed several executive actions in an attempt to bypass stalled negotiations with Democrats about a new stimulus bill amid the coronavirus pandemic. That included the LWA funding that provided $300 to $400 in extra unemployment insurance. But the funding is limited to up to $44 billion **redirected** from FEMA.

I met a problem reading this word "redirected" in this sentence.

Since I didn't know much about FEMA so I checked with [**the site**](https://www.investopedia.com/lost-wages-assistance-lwa-program-definition-5076976) about the (firstly) LWA and [**FEMA.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Emergency_Management_Agency)

They say,

> **The program(LWA) is administered by the Federal Emergency Management Agency (FEMA)** and applies to states, territories, or the District of Columbia, provided that entity applies by Sep. 10, 2020, and is accepted.

So am I right that the LWA is kind of a anti coronavirus stimulus package which is under?/or the successor to the FEMA? (But what connection does it have to do with Trump's memorandum? if they say **The program(LWA) is administered by the Federal Emergency Management Agency (FEMA)**)

Please disentangle my understanding about these programes with thanks in advance.

Comment: FEMA was not set up by the Orange Man. Federal Emergency Management Agency.

Comment: @Lambie Thank you lady. Please kindly read my completely revised version and if you could help me, I would appreciate it very much^^.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“redirected” in this case means that money previously allocated to one program has been reallocated to another program.

The political importance is that every year there is a months-long political standoff in Congress since they disagree on how much the government should spend in total and how they will pay for that spending. If you tried to *increase* total spending mid-year to pay for a new program, that debate would be reopened and nothing would likely get done. However, if you only move around money that Congress has *already agreed to spend*, that controversy can be avoided, so you can get it done relatively quickly.

FEMA is an *agency* that has existed for decades; they specialize in rapid response to crises, mostly natural disasters. When the new Lost Wage Assistance *program* was created, it was decided that FEMA was the agency best suited to run it because the pandemic presents similar problems to those they’re very experienced at solving.

Answer (score 1):

FEMA (the Federal Emergency Management Program) receives funding or funds from Congress.

FEMA has an annual budget of $18 billion[2] that is used and distributed in different states according to the emergencies that occur in each one. An annual list of the use of these funds is disclosed at the end of the year on FEMA's website.
[FEMA funding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Emergency_Management_Agency)

So, funds are given i.e. **directed to** FEMA.

The Orange Man took money by issuing executive orders from FEMA and gave it, i.e. redirected it to the Lost Wages Assistance program, set up to help people due to the COVID-19 crisis.

There is no other link between FEMA and LWA.

This is the second time the LWA will provide money to people who lost wages. The first time it was $600 and now it is $300. States have to apply for grants to get it. (And I think the money is running out).